# Protecting against rapid ajax calls

Tags: php, ajax

I have a very simple game where a user clicks a button that calls some php function via ajax. The php function logs the call and decrements the users ability to click the button by 1.

If a user spam clicks the button or forces calls to the php function then the user can run the php function hundreds of times in 1 minute.

Is there a way to stop this?

Simple server-side code to limit calls every 1500ms, or not as it turns out :)

```
$user = Utils::getUser();
$now = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
// run spin
if($user){
    $dif = $now - $user->last_spin;
    if($user->spins > 0 && $dif > 1500){
        $user->last_spin = $now;
        $user->decrement('spins');
        $user->increment('spin_count');
        $user->save();

        //do stuff
     }
 }
```

Comment: Disable the button after it has been clicked once?

Comment: You can't stop a user from making requests.  But in your server-side code you can track how often something is happening and return an error if it doesn't meet your business logic requirements.  Or at a more architectural level you could perhaps throttle requests at the web server or even at the router before they even reach the application.  Though that may be better suited for another Stack Exchange site.

Comment: The button does get disabled. But the the user can still spam ajax calls before the button is disabled. And disabling the button with js can easily be reversed by the user.

Comment: Look up "rate limiting".

Comment: @David, I already log the last button click time and compare times and reject click < 1500ms. But ajax spams still occur.

Comment: @xtremetom Combine that with disabling the button right away, and the spams shouldn't occur. Set a variable in javascript to lock the button, something the user can't change. Basically set a variable `buttonLocked = true`, check against this value and when the timeout is hit, reenable the button and change `buttonLocked = false`.

Comment: @xtremetom: Is your logic not successful in preventing the requested operation from taking place?  That is, when you "reject click < 1500ms", is there some way in which that logic is failing?  If you're asking about the programming itself, we'd need more information about the problem.  If you're asking how to prevent users from spamming your site at all, that's not really something the application code can solve.  That's more of a web server administration concern.  Your application can't prevent users from making requests.  They can manually craft any request they like.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton: *"something the user can't change"* - The user can change *anything* client-side.  The user is not even required to use the client-side code at all.  They can simply replicate the HTTP request in their own code.

Comment: Your 1500 ms reject needs to be *server-side*.

Comment: @ceejayoz it is, still not enough.

Comment: You need to show us your server-side code/technique enforcing that limit, then, as it's apparently not working.

Comment: @ceejayoz I added that code but honestly that doesnt seem to be the issue here. I looks more like a php processing time vs ajax call speed issue.

Comment: assuming you are using Apache, it may be a better idea to implement the rate limiting at that level, *before* it reaches any actual php code.

Answer (score 0):

To each request, store the microtime in session and check that session before executing the php code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['ajax_call']) || $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'] >($_SESSION['ajax_call']+1.5)){
  //ok, your code to run
}
$_SESSION['ajax_call'] = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'];
```